# Mirth Messages are missing from Admin Console

Tags: interface, activemq-classic, mirth

We use mirth as our interface engine and the ActiveMQ and Spring Inbound listener to process messages.

Our customers reported that some of the messages are missing from the mirth console but found in the ActiveMQ queue and the Spring listener application.

Initially we thought that someone may have removed manually from Mirth. But when checked the event logs there's no sign of removing a message.

We found this happening on some of the messages but could not identify the cause of the issue or pattern of messages.

Have anyone face and issue like with Mirth Admin console ?
We have the client DB as well but unable to open except through Mirth to check whether data is available.
Highly appreciate if someone can help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Good question.  I would like to encourage you to add it to the StackExchange proposal for IT Healthcare: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/51758/healthcare-it

Answer (score 0):

I have found some channels don't display "filtered" messages properly.  But I have never seen successful messages go "missing".

If you don't trust the Mirth Admin then I would recommend querying the Mirth DB.

This can be done outside the confines of Mirth provided that Mirth is writing to an external DB such as MS-SQL Sever.

The data you get from it is VERY rich, but if you are sending 1000's of messages an hour (or more) you'll probably want to limit the time-range you search.  Free-text searching like

```
select * from message m where m.raw_data like ('%needle%')
```

is NOT recommended and will take a long time to execute.

Being able search Mirth via the DB has opened up a tone of analysis for us that we don't have through the admin interface.

Comment: You'll also want to explicitly read with "no-locks" otherwise Mirth will have problems logging.

Answer (score 0):

Just to chime on this question:  if you are are running quite a number of channels or if you have quite a high volume of messages mirth may have trouble keeping up with its database updates due to row/table locks and inefficient conversions or data types (this should be resolved now).

We do, however, at peak times every so often, see a message or two processed through the engine with log entries indicating it was unable to insert the message and it was rolled back.  I would say we have around 10 per year like that.  Hopefully this is non-issue in Mirth 3 with the new backend ...